# Can you serve multiple subdomains from multiple servers on the same public IP?

Tags: dns, webserver, nginx, domain, subdomain

I have multiple Raspberry PI computers set up as web servers on my local network.


On RPI_1 I have `domain.com` and `sub1.domain.com`.

On RPI_2 I have `sub2.domain.com` and `sub3.domain.com`.

On my local network everything works fine with hostnames (i use local DNS function from PiHole).
I am running NGINX servers and I have the virutal hosts set up correctly.

What I am wondering is if it is possible to have one public IP and two NGINX web servers behind it on a local network and have the subdomains work correctly?

Comment: I am not aware of an easy solution for virtualhosts on NGINX involving a NATed network. [SRV records redirecting to a port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942372/can-i-configure-a-subdomain-to-point-to-a-specific-port-on-my-server) could be the solution in this case. Note that this will not work with browsers. It may also be possible with a cloudflare (or any other) proxy server

Comment: You could have have a reverse proxy that routes traffic based on subdomain, though this might make things slightly slower

Comment: @BarryCarter thank you, that led me in the right direction